# Зачем в коде if?

Tags: javascript

```js
function Calculator() {

  var methods = {
    "-": function(a, b) {
      return a - b;
    },
    "+": function(a, b) {
      return a + b;
    }
  };

  this.calculate = function(str) {

    var split = str.split(' '),
      a = +split[0],
      op = split[1],
      b = +split[2]

    if (!methods[op] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      return NaN;
    }

    return methods[op](a, b);
  }

  this.addMethod = function(name, func) {
    methods[name] = func;
  };
}

var calc = new Calculator;
```

1. Создается функция конструктор - это указывает большая буква в названии функции
2. В теле функции создается локальный объект который присваивается в переменную methods
3. В переменной methods создается 2 метода под названием минус и плюс
4. Calculate это метод объекта который будем создавать
5. В теле метода Calculate  параметр str будем превращать в массив
6. А что будем делать if ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если вы имеете ввиду эти строки:

```js
    if (!methods[op] || isNaN(a) || isNaN(b)) {
      return NaN;
    }
```

То здесь проверяется определена ли операция, и числа ли правый и левый агрументы. Например, это условие сработает если вызвать калькулятор с аргументом `"1 * 2"`, так как операции умножения не определено по умолчанию.

Comment: @sanmaiс Скажите я правильно понял когда мы создали объект this.calculate он имеет доступ к локальному объекту methods ?

Comment: Да, имеет. Почитайте про замыкания.

Comment: @sanmaiс замыкание это про функции, а тут создается объект